# Unpivot a single into two rows - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, unpivot

I'm trying to unpivot the below row but I'm facing troubles. Any help please?

Input:

```
Date        Time    Country_Championship    Game      Home_Team   Away_Team
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
19/07/2020  18:45   Albania: Superliga  Bylis Vs Laci   Bylis       Laci
```

Output:

```
Date        Time    Country_Championship    Game        Team
---------------------------------------------------------------
19/07/2020  18:45   Albania: Superliga  Bylis Vs Laci   Bylis
19/07/2020  18:45   Albania: Superliga  Bylis Vs Laci   Laci
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    u.[Date], u.[Time], 
    u.[Country_Championship],
    u.[Game],
    u.[Home_Team], u.[Away_Team],
    u.details
FROM 
    [Soccer_Analytics].[dbo].[Ins_UpcomingGames_Temp] t
UNPIVOT
    (details FOR [Date], [Time], [Country_Championship], [Game] IN ([Home_Team], [Away_Team])) u;
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In T-SQL, I would recommend a lateral join for this:

```
select x.*
from [Soccer_Analytics].[dbo].[Ins_UpcomingGames_Temp] t 
cross apply (values
    (date, time, country_championship, game, home_team),
    (date, time, country_championship, game, away_team)
) as x(date, time, country_championship, game, team)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. another thought was to create two CTE and union them. what is your opinion about it?

Comment: @Error1004: `cross apply` is more efficient, because it scans the table only once, while `union all` requires two scans.

Comment: thank you so much for your info. `Union All` get everything for both site and `Union` get only the distinct rows?